# Remove rows if they have two labels

Tags: r

Having a dataframe:

```
dframe <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), name = c("Amazon", "Google", 
"Google", "Yahoo"), label = c("pre", "after", "pre", "after"), 
    text_sth = c("other", "another one test text_sth another text", 
    "another text other", "another one test text_sth another text"
    )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

How is it possible to keep rows which only contains in column label pre and after for every user id detect in every name. Example of expected output:

```
 id name   label text_sth                                               
1 Google after another one test text_sth another text
1 Google pre   another text other
```

Comment: Please clarify "for every user id detect in every name". There is only one value for id in your example data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`, you can apply conditions separately to groups within the data frame. We can use the `filter()` function combined with the fact that `TRUE` gets treated as 1 and `FALSE` as zero in some circumstances. The `max()` function is applied within groups.

```
library(tidyverse)
dframe %>%
  group_by(id, name) %>%
  filter(max(label=="pre")==1, 
         max(label=="after")==1)
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `all` to check if all the required values are present in the group

```
library(dplyr)

dframe %>%
  group_by(id, name) %>%
  filter(all(c("pre", "after") %in% label))

#     id name   label text_sth                              
#  <int> <chr>  <chr> <chr>                                 
#1     1 Google after another one test text_sth another text
#2     1 Google pre   another text other
```

We can implement the same logic in base R

```
subset(dframe, as.logical(ave(label, id, name, FUN = function(x) 
                         all(c("pre", "after") %in% x))))
```

Or two ways in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dframe)
dframe[dframe[, .I[all(c("pre", "after") %in% label)], by = .(id, name)]$V1]
#OR
dframe[, .SD[all(c("pre", "after") %in% label)], by = .(id, name)]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
dframe %>%
  group_by(id, name) %>%
  filter(length(intersect(c("pre", "after"), label)) == 2)
```

Or use

```
dframe %>%
    group_by(id, name) %>%
    filter(n_distinct(label) == 2)
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dframe)[, .SD[length(intersect(c("pre", "after"), label)) ==2], 
           .(id, name)]
```